# Does anyone know what in this clearInterval makes it not clear?

Tags: javascript, loops, intervals

This is my js converted from coffee :

```
set_timer: function() {
  var _this = this;
  return this.timer = setInterval(function() {
    _this.set({
      time_to_complete: _this.get("time_to_complete") + 1
    });
    if (_this.get("time_to_complete") > 3) {
      console.log("End of clear.");
      return _this.reset_timer(_this.timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
},
reset_timer: function() {
  clearInterval(this.timer);
  return this.set({
    time_to_complete: 0
  });
}
```

And then its called as :

```
this.model.set_timer();
```

For some reason this doesn't clear, and my interval keeps producing those `console.log`'s

Here's another example of the same error but in Coffeescript, and namedspaced to `$` as mixin methods for underscore

```
set_timer: (model) =>
  $.timer = setInterval =>
    model.set time_to_complete: model.get("time_to_complete") + 1 
    if model.get("time_to_complete") > 3
      console.log "End of clear."
      _.reset_timer model
  , 1000

reset_timer: (model) ->
  clearInterval $.timer
  model.set time_to_complete: 0
```

Comment: You need to show how it's called.  My guess is `this` isn't binding as expected.

Comment: I'm guessing that `this` (in your clearInterval) is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already returned the function before you clear it. Clear it first, then return.

```
reset_timer: function() {
  clearInterval(this.timer);
  return this.set({
    time_to_complete: 0
  });
}
```

As for the value of `this`, be careful since `this` is determined by the way you call it, not how it is declared.

Comment: D'oh. I can't believe I didn't see that

Comment: I updated my answer, it still doesn't work though. Same issue

Comment: @Trip how are you calling `reset_timer`?

Comment: From within the `setInterval` function

Comment: @Trip can you do a `console.log` on what `this` is in `reset_timer` to check what `this` is?

Comment: `this` from within `reset_timer()` returns as my model. The same object model this that calls the `set_timer()`

Comment: I also know for certain its not being called twice, so there's no strange double instantiation or the likes..

Comment: @Trip can you check if `this.timer` is actually timer? Otherwise, I can't see anything else wrong. Clear cache or recompile maybe?

Comment: Ah that's the part I think might the answer. It just returns an integer count of 3. So I'm not sure if that *is* the counter

Comment: @Trip then it is a timer. Timers return an integer referring to the timer id. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: Hmm well thanks so much anyway for your time. I super appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I add this the beginning of my set_timer function, it works!

```
if (this.timer !== null) {
  clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```